# NHibernate many-to-many, unable to delete a row

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, orm

I've got following entities: Project, ProjectMapping and User, it's many to manyHere are the mappings:

```
public ProjectMembershipMapping()
{
    Property(pm => pm.IsAccepted, prop => prop.NotNullable(true));
    Property(pm => pm.Permission, prop => prop.NotNullable(true));
    ManyToOne(pm => pm.Member, mapping =>
                                   {
                                       mapping.Lazy(LazyRelation.NoLazy);
                                       mapping.Cascade(Cascade.All);
                                   });
    ManyToOne(pm => pm.Project, mapping =>
                                    {
                                        mapping.Lazy(LazyRelation.NoLazy);
                                        mapping.Cascade(Cascade.All);
                                    }); 

    ComposedId(pm =>                                          
                   {
                       pm.ManyToOne(prop => prop.Member);
                       pm.ManyToOne(prop => prop.Project);
                   });
}

public ProjectMapping()
{   
    Set(proj => proj.Members,
            mapping =>
            {
                mapping.Lazy(CollectionLazy.NoLazy);
                mapping.Inverse(false);
                mapping.Cascade(Cascade.All);
                mapping.Table("ProjectMembership");
                mapping.Key(k => k.Column("Project"));
            },
            action => action.OneToMany()
        );      
}

public class DevcoopUserMapping : ClassMapping<DevcoopUser>
{
        Bag(user => user.ProjectMemberships, 
            mapping =>
                {
                    mapping.Lazy(CollectionLazy.NoLazy);
                    mapping.Inverse(false);
                    mapping.Cascade(Cascade.All);
                    mapping.Table("ProjectMembership");
                    mapping.Key(k => k.Column("Member"));
                },
            action => action.OneToMany());
}
```

User can be a member of many projects. Now let's say I'm gonna unsubscribe him from project. Just deleting ProjectMembership object by ISession  object throws me:

```
deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations)[devcoop.Daos.ProjectMembership#devcoop.Daos.ProjectMembership]
```

On the other hand, when I first try to delete this ProjectMembership instance from Project and User (I delete it from the associations as was suggested to me), I get exception:

```
could not delete collection: [devcoop.Daos.Project.Members#1][SQL: UPDATE ProjectMembership SET Project = null WHERE Project = @p0]
```

Can anyone help? Supposedly I screwed up something around the mappings, but I got no idea what can this be.

Comment: I only managed to get deleting Project working by using hql queries in 3 transactions, well it's a messy workaround, not a solution. Are there any "best practices" about many-to-many in NHibernate because I clearly screwed something up around these mappings, but I cannot find what exactly

Answer (score 0):

before you delete the ProjectMembership instance, remove it from both the DevcoopUser.ProjectMemberships- and the Project.Members-collections.

I believe this should work:

```
  membership.Member.ProjectMemberships.Remove(membership);
  membership.Project.Members.remove(membership);
  session.Delete(membership);
```

And i think you should remove the CascadeAll from the ProjectMembership mapping. I'm not entirely sure, but i think it would cascade the delete to all members and projects in the collections mapped with CascadeAll, which you probably don't want to happen.

Comment: The problem is with these mappings I got now it causes exception:
could not delete collection: [devcoop.Daos.Project.Members#1][SQL: UPDATE ProjectMembership SET Project = null WHERE Project = @p0]
as I wrote in the question.

Comment: are you maybe saving the User and Project entities before you try to delete the ProjectMembership instance? If so, try to delete the ProjectMembership before you save User and Project. I don't get why NH tries to update the ProjectMembership table.